# How to add custom directive namespace?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have several types of users, each of which has its own password change window:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('Directives.UserType1.Modals.ChangePassword', [
        'Controllers.UserType1.Modals.ChangePassword'
    ]);

    app.directive('changePasswordModal', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            templateUrl: '/UserType1/Modals/ChangePassword.tpl',
            controller: "Controllers.UserType1.Modals.ChangePassword"
        };
    });

})();
```

and

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('Directives.UserType2.Modals.ChangePassword', [
        'Controllers.UserType2.Modals.ChangePassword'
    ]);

    app.directive('changePasswordModal', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            templateUrl: '/UserType2/Modals/ChangePassword.tpl',
            controller: "Controllers.UserType2.Modals.ChangePassword"
        };
    });

})();
```

And angularjs tells me that he doesn't understand which one to use.
I thought to use the same trick as with the controllers (dot notation), but i can't.

Please, help me to understand how can i avoid "Multiple Directive Resource Contention" problem:

> Multiple directives [changePasswordModal, changePasswordModal] asking
>   for template on:

P.S. Sorry for my poor English :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directive names cannot take dots and cannot have the same name under single application module.

You can have same directive name under different app modules but then you need to set the priority for those directives explicitly and all the directives gets executed when the directive is used in the template in the order of priority  ( descending ).

In your case, you can rename the directives to the following.

userType1ChangePasswordModal

userType2ChangePasswordModal

Hope this helps.